# How to call self-hosted TCP service without proxy?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, self-hosting, tcpserver

I created a `C# Self-hosted TCP service` having server code the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uris = new Uri[1];
            string address = "net.tcp://localhost:4345/DeviceService";
            uris[0] = new Uri(address);

            IDeviceService service = new DeviceService();
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service, uris);
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDeviceService), binding, "");
            host.Opened += Host_Opened;
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

`DataService` class has the following code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class DeviceService : IDeviceService
    {

        public byte[] ProcessMessage(byte[] message)
        {
            try
            {
                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message);

            }
            catch
            {
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.File, "Error decoding message.");
            }


            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a message reply");

            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

Now, in order to call this from a client I have this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to enter");
            Console.ReadLine();

            var uri = "net.tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:4345/DeviceService";
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            var channel = new ChannelFactory<IDeviceService>(binding);
            var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
            var proxy = channel.CreateChannel(endPoint);

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a message send");

            var response = proxy.ProcessMessage(bytes);

            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

            Console.WriteLine(data);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

The problem that I have is that we want to call this TCP service without creating a proxy. We want to send data to this TCP socket service by just calling the IP address and the port and without the need of trying to create a proxy and do `proxy.ProcessMessage(...)`

> Any clue or advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because it's against `WCF` concepts. You must use proxy to allow WCF handling a lot of internal staff for you like message framing, multiplexing etc.

If you want to use raw sockets - just use them. [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8) + [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8) or [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8) itself. Also check projects on github like [simplsockets](https://github.com/haneytron/simplsockets).